# Exporting photo from geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, esri-geodatabase, file-geodatabase

I have a lot of photos in the geodatabase, I want to export the photos to a file. How do I export the photos from geodatabse? What tools are used?

Comment: Are your photos stored as attachments?  What type of geodatabase are you using? Do you have access to ArcGIS for Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are attachments for a feature class, this is easy. Add this python script as an ArcToolBox script, assign the parameters to the script accordingly, and run it. Provide the feature class as the first parameter, and provide the folder where you'd like the photos to be written to.

If you have photos that use the same name, you'll need to modify the python script to handle that issue. But if your photos are all uniquely named, this script will do what you need.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import da
import os

inTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fileLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'ATTACHMENTID']) as cursor:
    for item in cursor:
        attachment = item[0]
        filename = str(item[1])
        open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
        del item
        del filename
        del attachment
```