# How create a new arctool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arctoolbox

I want create a custom script but the Toolset menu appear disable.

[image]

Comment: You're trying to edit the ArcGIS installation?

Comment: @Vince I trying to create [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176179/exporting-photo-from-geodatabase) Python script

Comment: By editing the ArcGIS installation. That won't work. You need to create a local toolbox first.

Answer (score 2):

Make a toolbox in ArcCatalog (right click > new > toolbox). Then right click on your toolbox and you can click New > Toolset

Comment: Ok, that work. Im trying to do this [example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176179/exporting-photo-from-geodatabase).  That ArcToolBox script is a Python Toolbox isnt?

Answer (score 2):

If you have written a script that works for you when you run it in your IDE, open the Catalog in ArcMap and scroll to 'My Toolboxes'. This is where you can create a tool from your own script. If you are making a script tool, choose add>script.

[image]